# Downloaded file is removed immediately by Chrome

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I am trying to download a shared file (shared via dropbox) on my Windows 10 laptop and as soon as I download it, Chrome removes the file. It says "Removed" at the status bar next to the file name and when I try using IE, I get another error:

> You need Administrator permission to make changes to this file.

I have checked permissions and I am the owner of my download folder. I even try running IE as an administrator, but the same thing keeps happening. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the whole name of the file, including the file extension?  Are you running any third-party antivirus?  Are you able to upload a generic text file and download it with the same steps?

Comment: That’s an anti-virus deleting your file. You sure you’re not trying to download a virus?

Comment: Thanks. I have disabled all virus protection but still getting the same error. And no, I know the file and the publisher so it is not a virus. Thank yoy

Comment: Try changing download location

Comment: I had the same problem in Chrome when opening a very long text document (78Mb) and using the "Save As" option. Fortunatelly that document was accessible from a link and I was able to get the document by right clicking over the link and selecting the "Save link As" option.

Comment: This must be Chrome refusing to save a large text file. I'm seeing this on OSX as well. Pretty crappy UX to just say "removed" with no warning etc. Chrome 88. I was trying to save it to the Downloads folder, so permissions should certainly allow that. Meanwhile I can save much larger binary files with no issue.

Comment: You know what's really weird? Edge (on OSX) has the exact same behavior. Safari doesn't but it mandates that you save in a "webarchive" format.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when trying to download something. I right clicked on the save link as button. I tried multiple times, but it only worked after renaming it. After that I opened it and it worked kind of. I had to restart my PC before it started working good though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue on Windows when trying to save a webpage as an HTML file. I found a work-around. I have no "Save link as" option when I right-click on the webpage, but when I chose "Save as", it gave me 3 options... to save only the webpage (HTML), to save as an MHTML, or save as a complete series of files (which did not include an HTML file, oddly enough).

So I tried the MHTML, which worked, the download proceeded. Then I found a free converter online to convert it back into an HTML file. Since the heading for this post is about this error where downloads are immediately removed... this option might help others who stumble onto this page.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).